# Getting more data while converting data int to float and doing division and Multiplying with int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, data-conversion

I have three columns as shown in below tableA

```
Student Day     Shifts
129     11       4
91      9        6
166     19       8
164     26      12
146     11      6
147     16      8
201     8       3
164     4       2
186     8      6
165     7      4
171    10      4
104     5      4
1834   134     67
```

I am writing a tvf to calculate Value of Points generated for Students as below

```
ALTER  function Statagic(
@StartDate date
)

RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(  
with src as
( select  

Division=case when Shifts=0 then 0 else cast(Day as float)/cast(Shifts as float) end,*
from TableA
)
,tgt as
(select *,Points=Student*Division from src
)
select * from tgt)
```

When i execute above tvf(select * from Statagic('3/16/2014'))
My output is below

```
129   11    4   2.75                     354.75
91    9 6   1.5                  136.5
166   19    8   2.375                    394.25
164   26    12  2.16666666666667    355.333333333333
146   11    6   1.83333333333333    267.666666666667
147   16    8   2                     294
201   8 3   2.66666666666667       536
164   4 2   2                      328
186   8 6   1.33333333333333       248
165   7 4   1.75                      288.75
171   10    4   2.5                   427.5
104   5 4   1.25                       130
1834 134    67  2                      3668
```

Note :
If you see the last row  for three columns in the table is the total of rest column.So when you see the last row in the Output of TVF for last two columns when i am adding i am not getting same data i am getting more.

Guys please help me i am struggling to fix this bug i tried in all ways but i am unable to fix it.

```
select 354.75+136.5+394.25+355.333333333333+267.666666666667+294+536+328+248+288.75+427.5+130=3760.750000000000
```

3668 is not euql to 3760.75(I am getting more 100 value)

Comment: Where is your variable @StartDate is being used in your function ??

Comment: @M.Ali Tvf function is not yet fully compeleted .I was stucked by here bcause i am not getting exact data.

Comment: Also could please explain what is this symbol in your calculation `select 354.75+136.5+394.25+355.333333333333+267.666666666667+294+536"+\328"+248+288.75+427.5+130`  the section between double quotes `+\\` what is this ??

Comment: @M.Ali..I am just adding all values expect last row.I think my mistake there is a back slash.I mean that if i add all values the values is more than the last row last column.

Comment: What you are doing in the last row is this `SELECT 1834 *cast(134 as FLOAT)/cast(67 as FLOAT)` and it is returning the correct result as `3668`. The other calculation you have shown in your question are summing totally different set of values. If this TableA is a view or a derived table you need to look into that. there is nothing wrong with your posted query.

Comment: @M.Ali...Sry i think u misunderstood my question if see the my data in the last row it is the total values of above values in that columns respectively.After doing division and multiplication the last rows of last columns are not matching if we add above values respectively??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49857/discussion-between-user3295524-and-m-ali)

Comment: This question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/ not here. You are trying to compare sum of all values with a product of its sum. Don't remember exactly what is mathematical term for this, but it is not equal. Someone on Mathematics would be able to explain it better.

Comment: There you go http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715397/what-is-mathematical-term-to-describe-this-confusion/715428?noredirect=1#715428 it has answer to your question.